# Disallow an element name in entire XML document using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am using XSD files to validate some XML files. One rule is that no script is allowed in the xml or specifically in this case xhtml document. 
I reckon that we need to specify in XSD file that no tag name = "script" is allowed in the entire document. How can this control be achieved?

As a beginner is XSD world I tried

```
      <xs:element name="script" maxOccurs="0"/>
```

but apparently it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

### XSD 1.0

You cannot directly express the constraint that no `script` element may exist in the document, but you can omit `script` and allow it no way in:  Simply do not use it in any the content models of any elements, and do not use `xsd:any` with `lax` or `skip` for `@processContents`.

### XSD 1.1

In XSD 1.1 you can use `xsd:assert` to restrict `xsd:any[@processContents='strict']` further (anywhere `xsd:any` is needed, or even for entire contents of the root element):

```
<xs:assert test="every $e in .//* satisfies $e[not(self::script)]"/>
```

Comment: In addition, XSD 1.1 has the option `<xs:any notQName="script"/>`. I've never seen a use for it before....

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm not able to test these solutions right away as the project is .Net and it does not support XSD 1.1. Maybe I should use Saxon for this problem...

Comment: Solutions were provided for both XSD 1.0 (supported natively in .NET) and XSD 1.1 (supported via Saxon in .NET).